# How to prevent page "jump" if anchor is in the URL when page loads?

Tags: jquery

How to prevent with jQuery default browser behavior, jump to anchor if anchor is in the link when page loads?

```
var myLink = document.location.toString();

if (myLink.match('#')) {
 $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 0); // OR
 $(window).scrollTop();
}
```

Or.... can't find solution... searched... and searched

Comment: Are you looking for a plugin? Here's one: http://jesseprice.com/jquery-slide-to-plugin/

Comment: @melee No, just need line of code to prevent jumping if anchor exist in link

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/

Comment: @roXon There is no event, page is loading

Comment: @Bobo ahh ok, sorry about that, I misunderstood.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use return false / event.preventDefault on your links

```
var myLink = document.location.toString();

if (myLink.match('#')) {
    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 0); // OR
    $(window).scrollTop();
    return false;
}
```

Or do you mean that you want o smooth scroll to the position of the ID you are refering to in your hash sign?

after reading your comments ignore this message.

maybe like this: http://jsbin.com/ajafor/4#hello

Comment: yeah, read you whant it on a load, not on a click event, will look into this :)

Comment: added a sample: http://jsbin.com/ajafor/4#hello you can use a number on scrollTo, and I used onload event on the window, may not be needed but it seems to work.

Comment: Maybe not "eye-smoothest" solution, but it works :) After few hours of searching, and testing, this one is the best... thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href="#" class="link">link Text</a>
$(function()
{
    $('a.link').attr('href','javascript:void(0);')
});
```

or add manually

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="link">link Text</a>
```

Comment: I meant when page loads, not onClick

Answer (score 0):

I did this by including [localScroll](http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jquerylocalscroll-10.html) and [scrollTo](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/ScrollTo), then simply call:

```
$(function () { $.localScroll(); });
```

Comment: Sorry I've just reread your question and realised I'm not actually answering the question you asked. I hope the advice is helpful however